# Choosing between US and EU Data Center on Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine

I am currently setting up a project on **Google App Engine**, and have noticed that under the *Advanced Settings* panel, there is the option to choose between a Data Center in the **EU** and a Data Center in the **US**. At this stage I do not know where the majority of my users will come from (assuming I get any at all), so how should I go about deciding between these two options? Is it possible to somehow have **both** and redirect a user to the relevant Data Center depending on their location?

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference in network latency between these two locations is negligible compared to all the other factors that go into a response time (query time, data transfer, etc.) There are few use cases where such small difference comes into play (online multiplayer games and the likes).

The biggest reason to choose the EU data center is to comply with the European regulations on privacy. If you work with medical data and such, you need to consult with a lawyer. Otherwise, choose the data center closest to you. You can always make adjustments and optimizations once you reach a critical number of users.

Comment: Thanks! You say 'you can always make adjustments' - is it possible to change the Data Center, or are you talking about different adjustments to this?

Comment: It depends on your app. For a vast majority of apps 50ms difference is not noticeable and not worth optimizing for, as you lose/compromise in other areas (two databases instead of one, etc.) Note that App Engine caches static content across many access points, so static resources (images, JS, CSS) will be served from locations even closer to your users than a data center. And if that is not enough, you can always use a CDN to speed it up even further.